# php file_get_contents("/tmp/some_file") not working php7.1

Tags: php, apache, php-7.1

I'm having a weird issue with reading the `/tmp/some_file` file.

- My PHP Version is **7.1.13-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1**
- Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server built:   2018-01-14T11:23:59
- File `/tmp/some_file` is `0777` for sure !

But `file_exists("/tmp/some_file")` or `file_get_contents("/tmp/some_file")` are both returning **false**

I have tried

```
$data =  file_get_contents("/tmp/some_file");
var_dump($data); //is false

// OR even this code outputs: Unable to open the file!
$myfile = fopen("/tmp/some_file", "r") or die("Unable to open the file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("/tmp/some_file"));
fclose($myfile);
```

None of above codes works and I don't get any error messages.
When I execute PHP code with the `www-data` user in terminal using the `php -a` mode or directly run `php myfile.php` all of the above functions are working fine and the file normally gets read.

Is there any effective way to debug this or it is somehow related to the PHP version?

**--- Update ---**

After some digging, I discovered that file located in any other directly read normally. Seems problem is with the `/tmp` directory but `is_readable("/tmp")` returns true and `file_exists("/tmp/some_file")` returns still false ...

Comment: The PHP functions do not throw [`Exception`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php) or any of its children. This class is the base class for user-defined exceptions.

Comment: ok thanks for this note @axiac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found issue answer here: https://serverfault.com/questions/614781/php-script-cant-access-tmp-folder?newreg=e8651c2bcaea4a718a38f4e1dc94805b

It is related to `ubuntu 16.04` and `apache`. For apache service **PrivateTmp=true** in this configuration file `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/apache2.service`.

That is why during executing php file via browser+apache result was false and via terminal it was true, as in case apache executing virtal /tmp directory been generated where no /tmp/some_file exists

Answer (score 0):

Try [error_get_last()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php)

> Get the last occurred error

For example:

```
$content = file_get_contents("/tmp/some_file");
if($content === false){
    print_r(error_get_last());
}
```

Or

```
$fp = fopen("/tmp/some_file", "r");
if($fp === false){
    print_r(error_get_last());
}

echo fread($myfile,filesize("/tmp/some_file"));
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: i get `failed to open stream: No such file or directory`. Evan file_exists return false so php somehow cant locate that file

Comment: i'm thinking can it be related to some kind of include path or something like that ?

Comment: Are you sure that file_exists?

Comment: 100% in terminal `cat /tmp/some_file` returns `test`

Comment: even above php codes executed in terminal by `php -a` also return positive results. only in case browser run it fails. Probably it can be related to Apache i'm still digging

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164066/discussion-between-thamaraiselvam-and-armen).

Comment: glad you know that you found the solution

Answer (score 0):

I have try "multi-user.target.wants" solution, it have worked but after restart, but at some point, PrivateTmp go back to true.
Like my principal use of Apache2 is PHP, I finally edited php.ini and I've uncomment line sys_temp_dir.

By default system use temp dir assigned by function sys_get_temp_dir. Function sys_get_temp_dir will return "/tmp" but the truth is that your tmp files are storing at some path like /tmp/systemd-private-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-apache2.service-YYYYYY//tmp/*. So, what work for me was:

Edit php.ini (path can change between PHP versions)

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
```

Then uncomment sys_temp_dir line

```
; Directory where the temporary files should be placed.
; Defaults to the system default (see sys_get_temp_dir)
sys_temp_dir = "/tmp"
```